# Soma no momento do INSERT com php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma soma no momento de um `INSERT` em uma tabela mas estou tendo dificuldades para realizar, no meu caso, a soma precisa levar em conta um agrupamento por número de telefone e usuário, por exemplo:

Telefone `99858-8888` do usuário `ID 77` teve `5` chamadas com seus valores, sendo:

```
0,73
0,75
0,85
1,25
8,29
```

Preciso somar esses valores e joga los na variável `ValorDebito` e realizar o `INSERT` agrupado.

A estrutura da minha tabela está assim:

```
    `IdItemProcesso` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Identificador único do item do processo',
    `IdProcesso` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Código do processo',
    `IdUsuario` INT(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Código do usuário',
    `NumeroTelefone` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Número do telefone',
    `ValorDebitado` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Valor debitado para o usuário',
    `Mes` INT(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Mês do processo',
    `Ano` INT(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Ano do processo',
```

Tentei algo, ficou assim:

```
foreach($ValorDebitado as $key=>$Soma) {

    $SomaValorDebito+= $Soma;

    // INSERINDO DO PROCESSO NA TABELA cpdItemProcesso
    $crud = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO cpdItemProcesso (IdProcesso,IdUsuario,NumeroTelefone,ValorDebitado,Mes,Ano) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $crud->bindParam(1, $IdProcesso, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(2, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(3, $NumeroTelefone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $crud->bindParam(4, $SomaValorDebito, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $crud->bindParam(5, $Mes, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(6, $Ano, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->execute();                   

}
```

Comment: Se é um campo calculado não seria mais prático criar uma view? Se quiser mesmo manter tal soma no banco crie um trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, tudo bem? Vamos lá!

Você disse:

> Preciso somar esses valores e joga los na variável ValorDebito e realizar o INSERT agrupado

Se você precisa somar os valores para só depois realizar o `INSERT`, a montagem do seu código está equivocada. Da forma como montou serão feitas várias gravações com valores incrementais e não agrupados.

Para fazer com valores agrupados, primeiro faça a soma em uma variável e faça a gravação após o `foreach`.

**Para um array com valores tratados:**
`$SomaValorDebito = array_sum ( $ValorDebitado );`

**Caso precise fazer algum tratamento:**

```
$ValorDebitado = ['0,73', '0,75', '0,85', '1,25', '8,29'];

//SETA UM VALOR PADRÃO PARA A VARIÁVEL, SENÃO DÁ PAU
$SomaValorDebito = 0;

foreach($ValorDebitado as $key => $Soma) {

    //Colocar os valores em formato americano para realizar a soma corretamente
    $SomaValorDebito += str_replace(',', '.', $Soma);

    // NÃO GRAVA NADA AQUI
}

// INSERINDO DO PROCESSO NA TABELA cpdItemProcesso
    $crud = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO cpdItemProcesso (IdProcesso,IdUsuario,NumeroTelefone,ValorDebitado,Mes,Ano) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $crud->bindParam(1, $IdProcesso, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(2, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(3, $NumeroTelefone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $crud->bindParam(4, $SomaValorDebito, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $crud->bindParam(5, $Mes, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(6, $Ano, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->execute();
```

Abraços!

Comment: Ual, obrigado @Tiago Sabatini, ajudou demais, valeu